# Port forwarding isn't working

Tags: ssh

I configured a raspberry pi with a local static ip on my home network - I can now ssh into it from my laptop when at home, using the local ip address.

I also have a 'global' ip address, and I'm trying to make the raspberry pi available for SSH at that address. I configured Port Forwarding (called Virtual Servers) for my TP-Link router, but it doesn't work. I'm attaching a screenshot of the configuration screen. [image]

Anyone knows what may be the problem?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a wrong gateway in the interfaces file for the eth0 interface.

Although the internal ip setup worked with gateway 10.0.0.1, I had to change it to 192.168.0.1 to make it work for port forwarding.